# Get class name of Parent View controller in iPhone Navigation push

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, push

I'm pushing a view like this.

`[[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];`

How Can I get class name of parent view controller from pushed view (child view)? `Any Idea?`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should do it:

```
NSUInteger numberOfViewControllersOnStack = [self.navigationController.viewControllers count];
UIViewController *parentViewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers[numberOfViewControllersOnStack - 2];
Class parentVCClass = [parentViewController class];
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(parentVCClass);
```

Comment: It would not bad, if you have checked you have more than 1 view controller on the navigation stack. If you try use it on root view controller, you will get an exception.

Comment: @Mert: that's true. I assumed the original poster can assert that there are at least 2 controllers on the navigation stack.

Answer (score 4):

Get class of parent view controller:

```
id class = [self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] class];
```

and its name:

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(class);
```

Comment: This would get the class of the navigation controller's root view controller, not necessarily the immediate parent of the top view controller (depending on the navigation stack).