# how to check what previous viewcontroller was open

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have ViewController A B and C. Form B and C I can navigate back to the ViewController A.

First shown is ViewController A after that user can either go to B or C

I want to present a message into a text box on ViewController A only if the if the user comes back from the ViewContoller C

So how can I identify/check if the user comes from that specific ViewController C ?

Comment: While jumping form one vc to another you could pass a flag/value to check at vc-A for which vc it came from. Also you could check out the stack for the one which pushed [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760175/get-class-name-of-parent-view-controller-in-iphone-navigation-push) for your reference

Comment: You can simply use a delegate for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You could use delegation to do this.

You could define a protocol, say, RootViewControllerDelegate.

RooViewController would have a delegate that conforms to this protocol.

Your TopViewController would conform to this protocol, which could have a method such as -RootViewControllerCompletedSomeThing, which the RootViewController could send when it is finished.

In TopViewController's implementation of this method, it could dismiss/pop RootViewController, and do whatever else it is that you want to do when RootViewController has been dismissed.

**Solution 2:**

You ca set NSUserDefaults to every view controller.

For example  For ViewController A

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"ViewControllerA"];
```

For example  For ViewController B

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"ViewControllerB"];
```

For example  For ViewController C

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"ViewControllerC"];
```

And In A Viewcontroller ViewDidLoad check belowCondition

```
-(Void)ViewDidLoad
{
 if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]ValueForKey:@"ViewControllerC"] isEqualToString:@"Yes"])

{
//Write your code.
}

}
```

Comment: tnx allot for your answer but I have a slight problem that the if statement is already true before I even was on the ViewController C

Comment: Solution 2 will fail if Go to C .Now you have set key to YES Then back to A It will work.Now  if I go to B & back to A ,It will show me Text in textView Because earlier I have set Key to Yes .One more thing is viewDidLoad will never gets called when I pop ViewController

Comment: One More thing to add you are making NSUserDefaults heavy .Which is not good practice beacuse it will stay in whole APP lifeCyle

Comment: @RohitKP Tnx for the tip !

Comment: @TamoDaleko:Which logic you are using now.

Answer (score 2):

- You can take one property in `A viewController` , just before you  push
  `B Or C ViewController` into the `navigationController` you can set this
  property with the nane of the `viewController` you are pushing.
- When you pop `ViewController C or B`,`viewWillAppear` of A gets called where you
  can set the `textField` with the name of controller if it is C you have set earlier while pushing.

//while Pushing C

```
ViewController *cViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cViewControllerID"];
self.viewControllerPushed = @"cVC";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cViewController animated:YES];
```

//while Pushing B

```
ViewController *bViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bViewControllerID"];
self.viewControllerPushed = @"bVC";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bViewController animated:YES];
```

//in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if([self.viewControllerPushed isEqualToString:@"cVC"]){
        //show in textField
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a example for that ?

Comment: @TamoDaleko, the answer given that is not less-then the example. Just go through the step suggested in answer and at least just try.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use delegate or notification pattern...
For ex **Notification Pattern**.

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "changeTextFieldData", name:kNotificationFromBackFromVcC , object: nil)



 func changeTextFieldData(){
     //set data as you want in your textfield...
    }
```

in your method...

and at the btnClick event in ViewController C
you can call...

```
`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(name:kNotificationFromBackFromVcC, object: nil`)
```

For ex. **Delegate Pattern**

in you ViewController C

```
protocol BackClickDelegate
{
    func backlickFromVC(isChange:Bool);
}
```

at btnClick event in ViewController C write

```
if self.delegate?.respondsToSelector(Selector("backClick")) {
    ... do your works            

}
```

in your viewcontroller A you can implement that delegate method .

```
  func backClick(){
}
```

Comment: it is tagged objective C

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface viewController(){
NSString strViewController;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(strViewController){
         if([strViewController isEqualToString:@"B"]){
               self.textFieldMsg.text=@"B";
         }
         else{
                self.textFieldMsg.text=@"C";
         }
    }
}


//Befor Puch to B or C from ViewController A just assigne value for variable strViewController

like 
strViewController=@"B" for pushViewController:viewControllerB

strViewController=@"C" for pushViewController:viewControllerC
```